# postForObject Solr query

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, solr

I am trying to run a Solr search and keep getting a 400 bad request.

From one of our linux boxes i can run this to search Solr:

```
curl "http://address.com:port/solr/core_name/select?indent=on&q=column:first_name,last_name"
```

This is what I wrote to try and run this query.

```
data class RoutingRequest(val columnNames: List<String>)

fun callSolrResponse(routingRequest: RoutingRequest): SolrResponse? {

        val headers = HttpHeaders()
        headers.contentType = MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN

        val request = HttpEntity(routingRequest.columnNames.joinToString(separator =","), headers)

        return restTemplate.postForObject(
                "http://address.com:port/solr/core_name/select?indent=on&q=column:",
                request,
                SolrResponse::class.java
        )
    }
```

If I leave off `select?indent=on&q=column:` and add it to the request I get a 404 not found.

Should i be posting the request as a JSON object maybe?

Changing it to a get request and using the entire URL works, will I run into a problem if the URL is too big? Idk how to get it working with a post request:

```
 fun callSolrResponse(routingRequest: RoutingRequest): SolrResponse? {

        val headers = HttpHeaders()
        headers.contentType = MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN

        return restTemplate.getForObject(
                "http://address.com:port/solr/core_name/select?indent=on&q=column:".plus(routingRequest.columnNames.joinToString(separator =",")),
                SolrResponse::class.java
        )
```

Comment: You have `http://` twice in the URL. Is that just on this question or is that also in your code?

Comment: just in this question, i censored some stuff, edited to remove

Comment: The Solr log should show you exactly what query was received (as long as it's set to the `INFO` level). It should tell you what query was actually generated.